# Simple Visualization library in Java to display data

Tags: java, graph, data-visualization, prefuse

I am looking for a good visualization library in Java for my school project in data mining.

So, my primary focus will be on data mining and I just need a simple API which takes in the output of my algo (xml, csv etc, not yet decided) and give cool looking analytic like view of the data.

So, I need a simple library which just works.

I liked [prefuse.org](http://prefuse.org), but will be be an overkill and time consuming? The app might be a web based or a java swing app (what ever is easy and quick to build).

**UPDATE**

[Large-scale RDF Graph Visualization Tools](http://www.mkbergman.com/414/large-scale-rdf-graph-visualization-tools/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can convert the output into graphviz dot format ([graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org)) than you can use idot incremental viewer ([iDot_incremental_viewer](http://stwww.weizmann.ac.il/g-cs/benari/idot/index.html)) which uses prefuse behind the scenes and it's completely free. **The only thing you need to do here is to convert the output in simple dot file**. Rest will be taken care of incremental viewer.

Answer (score 1):

you may take a look at Processing. 
there are also a lot of nice examples in openprocessing.org. There used to be a sister website called openvisualizations but it does not seem to exist anymore.